# Custom decorator for validation in nesjts - on a service layer

Tags: typescript, rabbitmq, decorator, nestjs

I have a subscribe on a nestjs **service** that got rabbit message

```
  @RabbitSubscribe({
    exchange: 'test'.
    routingKey: 'test',
    queue: 'q'
  })
  async handleEvent( msg: msgModel) {
    console.log(message)
  }
```

I have a lot of subscriber like this and I want to validate this model like we can do in a controller via validationPipe()

but validationPipe() or guard does not work on simple service

so I want to create a custom decorator that will get the message and will validate it

smth like:

```
  @CustomDec(msg)
  @RabbitSubscribe({
    exchange: 'test'.
    routingKey: 'test',
    queue: 'q'
  })
  async handleEvent( msg: msgModel) {
    console.log(message)
  }

or 
  @RabbitSubscribe({
    exchange: 'test'.
    routingKey: 'test',
    queue: 'q'
  })
  async handleEvent( @customDec() msg: msgModel) {
    console.log(message)
  }
```

is it possible to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be straightforward using a [method-decorator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#method-decorators). Something like this:

```
function MsgValidator(target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
    const originalMethod = descriptor.value;
    descriptor.value = function (...args: any[]) {
        const msgModel = args[0];
        console.log("validating msg ...");
        if(msgModel.message === "isExpectedMessage") {
            console.log("OK")
        }else {
            console.log("NOK")
        }
        return originalMethod.apply(this, args);
    }
}
```

Use it with:

```
  @RabbitSubscribe({
    exchange: 'test'.
    routingKey: 'test',
    queue: 'q'
  })
  @MsgValidator
  async handleEvent(msg: msgModel) {
    console.log(msg)
  }
```

Here's an example on [ts-playground:](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWQM4HMBqBDANjAE2yjgCcAKKbU9AUygC5FswBPAGkQAdS4vbSUVgGlarJqiikYYdJwK1UEaVxKkmABV79BrACKLlMVWQCUiAN4AoRLcS56iMjHQy8yegAs4BRAF5EBSUVNQA6ADc8EFoAbhs7AHoEgHdSbC4uGXREKE9aJ2lXMDxEAFsvH3jbIKMTUgio-IDQSFgERHJQrup0VCYWVgBtAF1zazsJxAgESTKMZB9aXH9mGlRBgAZhuMm7abBUOAdQ3Dh0cgAiSPwiWFk57K7Qi9Md3cQYYHJS%20cXcUPKqFQ2Do-j8AQuMFQAFEAB78aC0AgeIEg2gvSxVd62faHY6nc4XADywheWImAF8lqh8uNsXsZkdaCczpcAHIksnYinkuykeggUhIZxFdwVAihdJcXCsSieKGcHqoV5Ynk8qwQXDYIEPBYKZZ0nEzKQgaBkchcEAAI3wEDKimBdAYkmksjGaqsGq1OoAynByj6BOEYBBaIbEAABNBYPCEYhkWzxbWsSCITwsAgOaHhWhgKDkB5MH7oPVLMYTeIez24qCIVArMC0ZKIP0BoMh2jkFWoULpsCZ2jZ3P5xvN4ul3CXKFwhFQJEox3o0ymKw9vsDod58ij3V-S7gWjw2iIhdol6mIA)

Comment: thanks , it does not work in nestjs 

i added a console.log before the descriptor and I got it. , but dont get nothing inside the descriptor

Comment: hi ok when i put the MsgValidator below the @RabbitSubscribe it works but only on the second call 
it meanse 

1- got message- > print validating msg ...
NOK

2- got another message- > noting printed 

3- got another message- > print again

Comment: thx it will be great , and the wired thing is why its is print alternately

Comment: it works good when I. put it below so its ok 

do you know how can I inject a service into?  and how can I return a different value to the function

Comment: Since `this` inside the the decorator function refers to the service-class, you can inject your required service into the service where you have `handleEvent` and access it from there.

Comment: Great, don't forget to accept my answer, thank you :)

Comment: hi another question is how can i return a new model to function 

lets say in handleEvent I want a swtichCase 
that each case will need to handle a new Dto. or call to function like

case "event" :
  this.fun(message.data)


the and fun should accept "NewDtoModel"  that will converted from the message.data

i dont want to to "plainToClass" in the switch case itself 
I want it in the fun()

so if i tried to return new type from the decorator i will loose the typing

Comment: Could you please create a new question from this comment? I'll see what I can come up with :)